# Why for loop access only first row?

Tags: python

I  will try to find elements from the 2d array wherein each row's elements are sorted. I use for loop to access the row then apply binary search in each row. But for loop get stuck in row 1.

```py
def searchMatrix(self, matrix, target) -> bool:
    m = len(matrix) 
    print(m)

    for i in range(m):  
        print(i)
        if len(matrix[i]) == 1:
            if matrix[i][0] == target:   
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else: 
            start = 0;
            end = len(matrix[0]) - 1
            while start <= end :
                    mid = round((start+end)/2)
                    if(matrix[i][mid] == target):
                        return True
                    elif matrix[i][mid] > target:
                        end = mid - 1
                    elif matrix[i][mid] < target:
                        start = start + 1        
            return False
```

My output:

```
3
0
```

but output should be

```
3 0 1 2
```

Comment: You always return something on the first iteration so that's why the loop exists on the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop, all conditions will lead to a `return` statement, therefore the function will exit in the first iteration. You can remove all the `return False` and just add one as the **last** statement of your function:

```py
def searchMatrix(self, matrix, target) -> bool:
    m = len(matrix) 
    print(m)

    for i in range(m):  
        print(i)
        if len(matrix[i]) == 1:
            if matrix[i][0] == target:   
                # Only exit the function if you find the target
                return True
        else: 
            start = 0;
            end = len(matrix[0]) - 1
            while start <= end :
                    mid = round((start+end)/2)
                    if(matrix[i][mid] == target):
                        # Only exit the function if you find the target
                        return True
                    elif matrix[i][mid] > target:
                        end = mid - 1
                    elif matrix[i][mid] < target:
                        start = start + 1

        # Otherwise, keep iterating

    # Since all rows were searched, exit the function
    return False
```